# Connect to websocket from Windows command line

Tags: windows, websocket

Is it at all possible to connect to a websocket from the Windows command line?

I have used WSCAT from the Mac Terminal, but I can't seem to find an alternative.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can instal wscat on Windows (`npm install -g wscat`). It works just as it would work on other OS.

Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat

Answer (score 3):

There is no tool built in to Windows that will work with WebSockets.

Although you can use `telnet` or `netcat` to make a connection, they are simple TCP clients and know nothing about WebSockets.  So, either find a 3rd party WebSocket command-line client, or write your own.